# Partitioning ${\cal P}([[1,n]])$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

In an analysis of the Jacobi method for the computation of the spectrum of a Hermitian matrix, I face the following problem.

Denote ${\cal P}_2(n)$ the set of doubletons $\{a,b\}$ in $[[1,2n]]=\{1,\ldots,2n\}$. There are $n(2n-1)$ of them. I wish to partition  ${\cal P}_2(n)$ in equal parts $X_1,\ldots,X_{2n-1}$ of cardinals $n$, such that the union of the elements of any $X_\alpha$ is precisely $[[1,2n]]$ ($X_\alpha$ is a partition of $[[1,2n]]$) ? This can be viewed as a special  partition of the complete graph over $2n$ vertices.

For $n=2$, there is only one solution. For $n=3$, there is a unique solution, up to a permutation in $[[1,6]]$. Is there always a solution ? Is there a natural (group theoretic ?) way to build one ?

More generally, if ${\cal P}_m(mn)$ denotes the set of parts of $[[1,mn]]$ of cardinal $m$, can it be partitionned in equal parts $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ such that each $X_\alpha$ is a partition of $[[1,mn]]$.

Comment: $$\binom{mn}{n}=n \binom{mn-1}{m-1}$$ right?

Comment: @M.U. $\binom{mn}{m}=\frac{mn}{m}\binom{mn-1}{m-1}$ (you have a typo on the lhs)

Comment: ahh yes ... sorry: $\binom{mn}{m}=n\binom{mn-1}{m-1}$

Answer (score 11):

You are asking for a 1-factorization of the complete graph
$K_{2n}$. See the section "Complete graphs" of
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization for a simple
description of one of them and the number of them up to $n=7$.

Comment: In particular, note Baranyai's Theorem linked from that page, which I believe corresponds to the general $m$ case.

Comment: Nice. This page points out that a 1-factorization of the complete graph is nothing but a [round-robin] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament).